# A button in a view brings back the previous view on click

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view

I'm building an MVC app and I want to submit a form. So I did something simple like this. Here is the "DisplayItems" view:

```
@model List<MyApp.Models.Inventory>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Display Items";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Object Name</th>
            <th>Number In Stock</th>
            <th>Quantity To Send</th>
            <th>Reserved for First Template</th>
            <th>Reserved for Second Template</th>
            <th>Reserved for Third Template</th>
            <th>Number so far</th>
            <th>Input quantity</th>
        </tr>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(_x => _x[i].m_Obj.m_ObjName)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(_x => _x[i].m_QtyToSendShow)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(_x => _x[i].m_NbInStock)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(_x => _x[i].m_QtyFirstTemplate)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(_x => _x[i].m_QtySecondTemplate)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(_x => _x[i].m_QtyThirdTemplate)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(_x => _x[i].m_QtyHold)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(_x=>_x[i].m_QtyToSend)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="_submitButton" value="Confirm"/>  
}
```

Nothing extraordinary. However when the user clicks on the button "Confirm", the application keeps getting back to the PREVIOUS view which was a filter engine for the user to specify his search.

Here's the previous view named "SendItems":

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Send items";
}

<h2>Send Items</h2>

<p>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        Html.RenderAction("AdvancedSearch", "PartialViews");
    }

    @Html.ActionLink("Back to Selection", "MenuSelection")
</p>
```

The Partial view is a view binded to a model with many fields and an input button. When the button input is clicked, the controller method is hit like this:

```
public ActionResult SendItems(SearchEngineObject _searchObj, string _submitButton)
{
    if (_submitButton == "Search")
    {
        bool isValid = ValidateSearchFields(_searchObj);

        if (!isValid)
        {
            ViewData["ErrorMessage"] = m_MessageError;

            return View();
        }

        m_ListToManage = m_InventoryManager.ListAvailableInventoryItems(_searchObj);

        if (m_ListInventoryToManage.Count == 0)
        {
            ViewData["ErrorMessage"] =
                "There are no inventory items belonging to the parameters you selected; " +
                "please change your values and try again.";

            return View();
        }

        return View("DisplayItems", m_ListInventoryToManage);
    }

    return View();
}
```

So when the input button from the SendItems view is hit, the controller validates the fields, then retrieve the list of inventory items based on the filter and send it to the "DisplayItems" view.

But freshly arrived in the view, if I click on the "Confirm" button, it directly sends me back to the "SendItems" view, while I want it to go to the "DisplayItems" controller method. Why? Can anyone explain me what I did wrong?

**EDIT**

I did a quick debugging session and I can confirm that the debug sends me back to the "Send Items" controller method instead of hitting the "DisplayItems" method.

Comment: You are using the same **action method** for different *actions*. That's not a proper MVC structure. I'd recommend you to split that actions accordingly.

Comment: You mean that both views calls to the same ActionResult method?

Comment: What he's saying is that when the user first requests the page it goes to `SendItems`, but then when the postback from the form occurs, it just goes to `SendItems` again, so you'll keep getting the same thing over and over again. You need the postback to go to a different method.

Comment: Yeah. Each **action method** should have one assignment only. So, you would have one action (and it's *view*) to fetch the list, and another method to display the selected item's details.

Comment: Ah, ok. So basically I need to make a HttpPost / HttpGet for each method and I'll be ok?

Comment: That's one way to do it, or you can explicity specify which method should handle the form posting (there should be an override in `BeginForm` that handles this).

Comment: @HerveS Please, take a look on my answer

Comment: @sircodesalot well, using : `@using (Html.BeginForm("DisplayItems", "DispatchItems", FormMethod.Post))`, it finally worked, though I suspect this is not a proper way of MVC structure ;)

Comment: Sure thing. On the one hand, that method exists for a reason so don't completely discount it (just file it away as another tool for later). But for your purposes, using the `[HttpGet]`/`[HttpPost]` attributes may be a bit cleaner. Of course, instead of posting back to `DisplayItems` it would just post back to `SendItems` but the one marked `Post` rather than `Get`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be off base with this one, but one thing you can do is tag your Action methods with `[HttpGet]` and `[HttpPost]`, so that the execution will follow different paths depending on whether it's the original page `get` or form `post`-back, as in:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // The original page render will go here
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyModel());
    }

    // The form postback will go here
    [HttpPost]
    public String Index(MyModel model)
    {
        return "Something";
    }
}
```

Here is a simple mockup just using regular HTML:

```
<div>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name ="FirstName" value ="@Model.FirstName" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

but you can really do the same thing with your `Html.BeginForm` (set the method to 'post' rather than the default 'get') as well, just indicate that it should be a `post` rather than a `get`, and it should route to the same action method, but with the post tag instead of the get tag.

Answer (score 1):

Let's talk about organizing things up to avoid more than 1 assignment for each action method.

I'm not sure if I got your model right, but let's pretend you have a list of *items* and you want the user to select one item to show details, okay?

**UPDATE**: There's a `POST List` in order to filter the list.

Your server side would like like this:

```
public class ItemController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult List()
  {
    //fetch from db
    return View(yourViewModel);
  }

  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult List(string firstLilPig, int secondLilPig, string thirdLilPig)
  {
    //fetch from db using the little pigs as filters
    return View(yourViewModel);
  }

  public ActionResult Details(int id)
  {
    //fetch one item using the id
    return View(theItemViewModel);
  }
}
```

Doing this, you would have 2 views: **/Item/List.cshtml** and **/Item/Details.cshtml**. You won´t have a third view for the `POST List`. It uses the same /Item/List.cshtml, what changes is the *view model* (the data you pass for it).

Finally, you URL to browse/hyperlink this would be like:

- `http://.../item/list`
- `http://.../item/details/1`

---

**UPDATE**

According to your use case, I'd recommend the following structure:

**Search**
Method: `GET`
Parameters: none
View: Search

**List**
Method: `POST`
Parameters: filter criteria
View: List or Search if result is empty

**Request**
Method: `POST`
Parameters: list of items id and quantity (from the result table)
View: None. Saves stuff to database and redirects to Result

**Result**
Method: `GET`
Parameters: none
View: Result. Shows the result of the previous request

Notes:

1. The order is: Search > List > Request > Result. List may redirect back to Search
2. Request > Result is following the **PRG** principle. This way, if user hits F5 on the result page, request won't be resubmitted.
3. You should work on a view model for Request. It would have an array of ItemRequest, which would have ItemID and Quantity as properties.

Comment: I think that my structure is kinda messed up.

Comment: @HerveS Let me know if you have any further question.

Comment: I need a view to filter the choice, then a view to display the list obtained. How could I do this? And then apply an action on that displayed list?

Comment: Note that with sircodesalot's comment, I managed to override the Html.Beginform method, and now it works, but I know that it's not a proper way to do things, so I'm ready to listen :)

Comment: @HerveS Updated to add 1 action to filter the list

Comment: If I understand well what you are presenting me, the view to display the filters and the view that displays the list are the same, is that right?

Comment: @HerveS Yes, consider the following use case: (1) user browses to *items* page (2) all items (or most popular items, or top 10 items, or "refine your search" message is displayed (3) user submits filtered search (3) user receives search result (4) user click on an item to see details (5) user gets full details page of that item

Comment: Well, I'm confused. I wanted to avoid this since the search filters I'm using are rather massive, and I want to contain any actions to the list displayed. Are there any way to tell an input bouton to actually "Load" a new url / page? Else I don't know how to do this.

Comment: @HerveS Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Could you explain with user steps, like the use case I presented above?

Comment: All right, I'll try: (1) User browses through menu to manage Items. (2) user has to filter his search (I can deal with thousands of data, so I need a quick way to do this) (3) user sees his list of items and decides which quantity he needs of each (4) user confirms the quantity and the app process, showing confirmation / errors.

Comment: @HerveS there you go. An upvote would be interesting by now, at least for the consulting service =)

Comment: One of the things that I did NOT do, and thought about through the night, was to `return RedirectToAction`, which now calls the proper actionMethod. That's nice!

Comment: Yeah, you're getting into it =)